# Solve for $x$ in $\log_{1.1}(x) > x$

Tags: calculus

$\log_{1.1}(x) > x$

I tried:

$$\log_{1.1}(x) > x \Leftrightarrow 1.1^x > x \Leftrightarrow \log(1.1^x) > \log(x) \Leftrightarrow x\log(1.1) - \log(x) > 0 \Leftrightarrow \\ x\log(\frac{1.1}{x}) > 0 \Leftrightarrow \log(\frac{1.1}{x}) > 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1.1}{x} > 1 \Leftrightarrow 1.1 > x$$

But this is wrong. You can see the solution here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_%7B1.1%7D(x)+%3E+x

What did I do wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: I looking at your link observe a curious fact (especially when dealing with Wolfram): the straight line (in red) should have a slope of 45º but it is clearly lower (approximately 15°).

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake
\begin{equation}
x\log(1.1)-\log x>0\ne x\log \left(\frac{1.1}{x}\right)>0
\end{equation}

because there is $x$ multiplying $\log(1.1)$. You should solve it graphically because it is a transcendental equation.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I rewrite

$$f(x):=\ln x-x\ln1.1>0.$$

The derivative of the LHS

$$\frac1x-\ln1.1$$ has a single root, so that the original equation has at most two roots, let $x_0,x_1$.

By trial and error (exponential search), $f(1)<0,f(1/\ln1.1)>0,f(64)<0$, which proves and isolates the roots.

Then $$x\in(x_0,x_1)$$ where $x_0,x_1$ can be determined numerically.